Source for One who is occupied with a mitzvah is exempt from [another] mitzvah
A halachic principle is:

עוסק במצוה פטור מן המצוה
One who is occupied with a mitzvah is exempt from [another] mitzvah.

Where in the Sources is this principle expressed in these exact words?

Sukkah 26a brings a Braisa that attributes the formulation to R' Yosei HaGelili:

תַּנְיָא, אָמַר רַבִּי חֲנַנְיָא בֶּן עֲקַבְיָא: כּוֹתְבֵי סְפָרִים
תְּפִילִּין וּמְזוּזוֹת, הֵן וְתַגָּרֵיהֶן וְתַגָּרֵי תַגָּרֵיהֶן
וְכׇל הָעוֹסְקִין בִּמְלֶאכֶת שָׁמַיִם, לְאֵתוֹיֵי מוֹכְרֵי תְכֵלֶת —
פְּטוּרִין מִקְּרִיאַת שְׁמַע וּמִן הַתְּפִלָּה וּמִן הַתְּפִילִּין
וּמִכׇּל מִצְוֹת הָאֲמוּרוֹת בַּתּוֹרָה, לְקַיֵּים דִּבְרֵי רַבִּי
יוֹסֵי הַגְּלִילִי, שֶׁהָיָה רַבִּי יוֹסֵי הַגְּלִילִי אוֹמֵר:
הָעוֹסֵק בְּמִצְוָה פָּטוּר מִן הַמִּצְוָה.‏

